# Rails insert into model and association .. confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm confused writing my backend for the barangay profiles. In my form there is a field where ask to input the your barangay then when it save the barangay field will be save at the barangay model. In the brgyprofile it is associated to barangay model where the id of barangay model is FK of brgyprofile model. How can I save the data in barangay model. I already try to twerk it but nothing happens. brgy_name didn't save in the barangay model. I'm confuse how. I'm really new to rails and trying to create an app.

routes.rb

```
resources :brgyadmins do
    resources :brgyprofiles
  end
```

models

```
class Brgyprofile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :barangay
    belongs_to :brgyadmin
end

class Barangay < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :brgyprofile
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@brgyadmin,@new_profile]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :firstname, placeholder: 'Firstname' %>
  <%= f.input :lastname, placeholder: 'Lastname' %>
  <%= f.input :birthdate, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
  <%= f.input :gender,
    :as => :radio_buttons,
    :collection => %w[Female Male]
  %>
  <%= f.input :brgy_name, placeholder: 'Barangay' %>
  <%= f.input :brgy_position, placeholder: 'Barangay Position' %>
  <%= f.input :contact_number, placeholder: 'Contact Number' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

brgyprofile controller

```
class BrgyprofilesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_brgyprofile, only: [:new, :create]

    def new
        @new_profile = @brgyadmin.build_brgyprofile
    end

    def create
        #respond_to do |format|
            if @brgyadmin.create_brgyprofile(profile_params) && Barangay.create(brgy_name: params[:brgy_name])
                logger.info "Saved!"
            else
                logger.info "Nothing happens"
            end
        #end
    end

    private

    def set_brgyprofile
        @brgyadmin = Brgyadmin.find(session[:user_id])
    end

    def profile_params
        params.require(:brgyprofile).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :birthdate, :gender, :brgy_position, :contact_number, :barangay_id, :brgy_name)
    end

end
```

Comment: You tried to *twerk* it? :O

Comment: twerk the code Sir.. :D